# 2D collision detection without axis alignment

Tags: algorithm, 2d, collision-detection, collision

I'm looking for an algorithm solving a problem with detecting collisions between non-aligned objects in 2d (e.g. rectangles), as below:
[image: Collision example]

How do I go about it? All of the articles I found online handle axis-aligned objects, which is not what I need.
As for know, I handled only collisions between circles by measuring distance between their centers, but this case is way more difficult.

Comment: Just rotated rectangles or also less convenient shapes?

Comment: Several answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278665/how-to-check-if-two-rectangles-intersect-rectangles-can-be-rotated)

Comment: You can rotate both rectangles simultaneously sothat one of them become axis aligned, and the problem becomes much easier.

Comment: or just test the circumference lines for intersection ...